# Odds of getting a stand-by seat on July 4th in the US

Tags: air-travel, public-holidays, standby

I'm needing to fly one way from SEA to MCI on 4th of July weekend. I work for an airline (a cargo airline) and I'm planning on purchasing non-rev interline standby tickets. I have some flexibility since I don't have to be back in KC until the 6th. Being that the 4th is on a Monday would I have better luck getting a seat ON the 4th or should I plan on trying to get out Sunday night? I've heard Sundays are usually bad, but I have no idea how Monday holidays affect things.

Most likely airline would be Alaska Airlines. They have the most non-stop flights between SEA and MCI.

Comment: If I had to be somewhere over a holiday weekend, I would buy a ticket, not travel on standby (ps I am not the OP Tom ;-)

Comment: @Tom Fixed that. For some reason some of my SE sites just have me as "Tom." I've had the same problem on a different site. Had everybody really confused for a bit

Comment: @Tom Oh, and unfortunately moving my daughter up there has me broke. Trying to squeeze every penny I can.

Comment: I am not a regular Seattle flyer, but would hazard a guess that the traditional late Sunday business crowd, would switch to late Monday due to the holiday, so as to be ready for the start of the shortened work week on Tuesday.  Personally I would look at lists on Sunday, if loads are low, go for it.  That would give you Monday morning as a fallback.

Comment: Low is the answer. Flights are full in advance and then spare seats go to irrop'd revenue passengers.

Comment: Anyway, flying standby means that if flights really are full, you don't go at all.  Is your trip really that inessential that this would be acceptable to you?

Comment: @NateEldredge The trip is essential but I have a couple days flexibility on the date. I noticed that $164 yesterday and that's prob what I'm going to do. My co-workers who travel rarely run into problems. Usually just waiting one flight. But I don't know how 4th of July holiday affects things. Non-rev flights get harder to do all the time as the airlines refine their statistical predictions.

Comment: "Interline standby tickets" implies non-rev travel for industry employees. The question might be slightly more clear if this was more directly stated.

Comment: Interline standby is the lowest priority. I think you have near zero chance of getting to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are pretty bad since your ticket is just about the lowest in the pecking order and it's a really busy travel weekend.

You can monitor prices for the flights: if they go up, seats are filling quickly.  If they stay or go down, there is plenty open.

Current low bidder for 7/4 is Alaska at $160 non stop. 7/3 seems fuller: American offers a one stop for $170 and the cheapest non-stop is $250.

I'd recommend taking the 7/4 $160 option right now. It's a guaranteed non-stop as compared to a nail biter.

Comment: There was an interesting answer in another topic when someone wanted to travel on Christmas day (or +- few days) and another person has been comparing prices from November till December and finally the prices did rise. So the moral is, if risks are high and prices are low now - buy the ticket now, otherwise the price will only go up.